# How to resize and move to the center the ng bootstrap carousel?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the ng bootstrap in my angular project but I've a problem with its style.
Actually, it doesn't display to the center but in the upper left corner:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJbdf.png)

I want it to be centered and wide under the blue headbar.

I tried to work with CSS but the only similar result I get is to manually set the image to be like that:

`style="width: 100%; height: 877px"`

But I think it's not the best solution.

How can I do?

UPDATE WITH CODE:

```
    <div class="carouselCont">
    <ngb-carousel *ngIf="top10">
          <ng-template *ngFor="let film of top10.items" ngbSlide >
          <div class="picsum-img-wrapper" (click)="onClick(film)">
            <img src="{{film.image}}" alt="Random first slide" style="width: 100%; height: 877px"/>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-caption" (click)="onClick(film)">
            <h3>{{film.rank}} - {{film.title}}</h3>
            <p>{{film.year}}</p>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you also include your code ?

Answer (score 0):

a ngb-carousel, by defect is 100% width. You can use, e.g.

```
ngb-carousel 
{
    max-width:250px;
    margin:auto
}
```

You also can "wait to load the first img and get the max-width the width of this image

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" [style.max-width.px]="width">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
            <img #img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide"
             (load)="setWidth($event.target)" />
        </div>
  </ng-template>
 ...
</ng.carousel>
```

And define:

```
width=0;
setWidth(target:any)
{
    this.width=target.naturalWidth;
}
```

(don't forget the margin:auto in your .css)

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxskqt?file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel-basic.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel-basic.ts)

Comment: Hi @Eliseo thanks for answering.
I still have the same problem, it look like that:

[how it looks][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTvvO.jpg

I modified the code as you suggested and set the CSS with margin auto